# When did 'some one' turn to 'someone'?

Tags: orthography, history, historical-change, spacing

I was recently reading a book from sometime in the first half of the 20th century and I noticed that the word ‘someone’ was spelled separately as ‘some one’.

Was there an official change at some point, or what’s the difference?
Am I missing something?

(*some one, help!*)

Comment: "Some one" as a phrase has always existed alongside the word *someone*, what makes you think it was the phrase that changed?

Comment: Because we don’t use some one nowadays @kirs

Comment: As I recall, it was just a sentence - don’t remember what book @sumelic

Comment: If you want to know when it first happened, that probably was when Grog was carving Paleo-English on a cave wall.  Many such "adaptations" occurred in the era of handwriting, before mechanical printing became common.  And then the typesetters became the "authorities" for 100-200 years.

Answer (score 1):

A [Google Books NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=someone%2Csome+one&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csomeone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csome%20one%3B%2Cc0) shows that the closed compound *someone* did not overtake the open *some one* until the 1930s, the open compound virtually disappearing not long thereafter.

[image]

[The *New English Dictionary*, vol. IX,1](https://archive.org/stream/oed9aarch#page/n422/mode/1up) (1919), for instance, the predecessor of the OED, lists both, while the [1941 *Webster's Collegiate*](https://archive.org/stream/websterscollegia00webs#page/948) only has an entry for *someone* with no alternate spelling.

There does not appear to have been any controversy over the use of a closed versus an open compound. Both the [London 1875 edition](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.32044038404018;view=2up;seq=138;skin=mobile) of Richard Morris’s *Elementary Lessons in Historical English Grammar* and the identical [1879 New York edition](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.32044102855350;view=2up;seq=140;skin=mobile) list *someone* as a compound, but use *some one* in the text:

> Compounds of **some** are **somebody, something, someone, somewhat**.
>   …
>   **Some one** arose in the early part of the fourteenth century, and replaced *sum man*; it is also used where in M. E. *oon, one*, **some one** was employed.

The general tendency with frequently used compounds is toward a closed spelling unless it would result in adjacent vowels, which is the reason *someone* was the last *some-* compound to close and why [*no one/no-one*](http://grammarist.com/spelling/no-one-noone/) ever will.